# How to have two different background colors for a container

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, containers

### I want a container to look like this:

[image: battery]

The `backGround color` which is `red` is depent on how much battery the device has. I want it to be dynamic.

I tried it this way:

```
return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 100-battery,child: SizedBox()),
          Expanded(flex: battery,child: Container(child: Text(battery.toString()+'%', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,),),color: Colors.green)),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
    );
```

It looks good and the problem is that the `Text` is aligned to one side. I want it to be on one side. So I have to specify two `background color` to solve this. Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Made it better:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,//Starting point
          end: Alignment.centerRight,//Ending point
          stops: [0.5, 0], //First Part is the amount of space the first color has 
          //occupy and the second parameter is the space that is to be occupied by
          //mixture of both colors.
        colors: [Colors.green, Colors.amber], // List of colors
        ),
```

Comment: Fantastic, Life-saver answer

Answer (score 3):

Use `gradient` parameter of `BoxDecoration`

### You can use one of three gradients

- Lineargradient
- RadialGradient
- SweepGradient

### Take this for example

```
 Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: RadialGradient(
          center: Alignment.center,
          colors: [const Color(0xFF283250), const Color(0xFF0C1225)],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: 100 - battery, child: SizedBox()),
            Expanded(
                flex: battery,
                child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      battery.toString() + '%',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Learn more about using `gradients` from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Gradient-class.html

Comment: is there a way to make it little more clear? It is blur now @Kherel